# CMS Opencart 2.1 Как после оформления достать статус заказа

Tags: php, cms, opencart, order

В общем клиент заполняет формы, метод оплаты, метод доставки и далее нажимает подтвердить заказ и попадает на страницу /index.php?route=checkout/success . Мне нужно чтобы помимо надписи бла бла бла выходила надпись статуса заказа, например как на странице история заказов!!

*№ Заказа   Статус     Добавлено    № Товара     Клиент       Всего

26          Pending   12.08.2017    1            Артур      $1787.60*

Как это можно вывести копался в контроллере \catalog\controller\checkout\success.php

Но кроме всякой лажи unset($this->session->data) и $this->cart->clear() ничего не нашел

Comment: P/s/ нужен только статус заказа остальное неважно

Answer (score 0):

Все разобрался нужно в контроллере \catalog\controller\checkout\success.php

прописать следующее

```
$this->load->model('account/order');
$results = $this->model_account_order->getOrderHistories(26);
$data['status'] =$results; //и определить точку выхода в шаблон tpl
```

например так в \catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\success.tpl

```
 echo json_encode($data['status']);//в шаблоне tpl
```

на выходе имеем: [{"date_added":"2017-08-12 21:47:17","status":"Pending","comment":"","notify":"0"}]